resolving file references using web/dev-server vs regular live server
What's so special about @web/dev-server ?
index.html :
<script type="module" src="dist/my-elements.js"></script>

dist/my-elements.js : (was compiled using tsc 5.5)
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit';
import { customElement, property } from 'lit/decorators.js';

When I run npx web-dev-server --node-resolve --watch --open
http://localhost:8001/ shows the page without errors.
But if I run php -S localhost:8001 (or VSCode Live Server) and goto http://localhost:8001/ console shows :
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lit". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

How does it resolve using @web/dev-server ?
